# My regular expression doesn't work

Tags: java, regex, runtime-error, illegalstateexception

I tried to extract values using a regular expression, but when I tried to print the output this exception appeared:

```
Exception in thread "Main Thread" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:468)
    at TEST.main(TEST.java:21)
```

This is my code:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class TEST {
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String string = "10/06/2013 01:45";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([0-9]{1,})/([0-9]{1,})/([0-9]{4}) ([0-9]{1,}):([0-9]{1,})");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

        System.out.println(matcher.group(1)+"\n"+matcher.group(2)+"\n"+matcher.group(3)+"\n"+matcher.group(4)+"\n"+matcher.group(5)+"\n");
    }
}
```

Why is this code not working?

Comment: This may not be required to solve your problem, but it'd be helpful if you showed us your *expected* output.

Comment: Which line is 21? Please mark that.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to match parts of a date/time. You should use a [`DateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: better put your `group()` method calls i separate `println()` methods. That will give you more detailed output.

Comment: A single blank line of white space is always enough.

Answer (score 4):

You never called `match()` or `find()` before calling `group(int)`. The exception message describes this by saying the method was invoked at an illegal state -- it cannot tell you what is at `group(1)` before it has processed the input!

Comment: i called 
    matcher.find()
and it worked thank you very much